# What is the default proxy of Invoke-WebRequest if no proxy is given in the command line

Tags: windows, powershell, http, proxy, ntlm

I logged in to my client's server (Windows 2008 Server Standard) and tried to download something in command line. So I use the following command:

```
Invoke-WebRequest "http://www.example.com/somthing.cab
```

But then I got the following error message:

> ```
> Invoke-WebRequest : Authorization Required
> Description: Authorization is required for access to this proxy
> At line:1 char:1
> + Invoke-WebRequest "http://www.example.com/something.cab"
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
> ```

Moreover I am able to download that file in IE and IE doesn't use any proxy server. None of other command line tool can download via HTTP or HTTPS protocol (FTP is downloadable). There is no environment variable that specifies any proxy server.

What is the default proxy of `Invoke-WebRequest` and how do I know the proxy server ip address and port number and if it is an NTLM proxy server ?

Thanks

Comment: Install Wireshark and trace the traffic, you'll be able to see the difference in what IE does and what the rest do.

Comment: I don't have the permission.

Comment: Try [`netsh winhttp show proxy`](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc731131).

Comment: It said Direct access (no proxy server).

Comment: If this happens for all hosts, you may just have to go back to your client and tell them to either give you the proxy details or allow a network trace or give you some other way of getting the file. If you have to work with a locked down setup, they should at least be able to tell you how they plan to get work done.